# MySQL cannot find table assigned with alias

Tags: mysql, alias

I have a query...

```
select distinct(sod.sod_no), so.`so-no`, p.product_name, pod.prodstatus, po.`po-no`
                            from so_details sod
                            left join `sales-order` so on sod.so_number = so.`so-number`
                            left join products p on sod.product_id = p.product_id
                            left join po_details pod on sod.so_number = pod.so_number
                            left join `purchase-order` po on pod.po_number = po.`po-number` 
                            where so.status = 'In Progress'
```

But it errors:

```
#1146 - Table 'po.po-no' doesn't exist
```

The weird thing is that it can read the `sales-order` table without any problems. What might be the problem?

Comment: on the first join why you are using PO table? 
`left join `sales-order` so on sod.so_number = so.`so-number`, po.`po-no``

Comment: Please be aware that DISTINCT is not a function. And the inclusion of '-' in column identifiers is verging on reckless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this line?

```
left join `sales-order` so on sod.so_number = so.`so-number`, po.`po-no`
```

I think you can just remove the `, po.po-no` part.  It looks like a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line:

```
left join `sales-order` so on sod.so_number = so.`so-number`, po.`po-no`
```

I don't know why it has `po.po-no`. Also at this point your query still does not know about alias `po`.

---

I suggest using unified style for naming tables and columns. In SQL it's usually `snake_case`, but it seems like you are using `_` and `-` in same database.